# Error in Laravel Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching, laravel-7

I am beginner in php and Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 7.
I have repository pattern in my project with cache.

PageServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(PageRepositoryInterface::class, function ($app) {
        return new CachingPageRepository(
            new PageRepository
        );
    });
}

public function provides()
{
    return [
        PageRepositoryInterface::class,
    ];
}
```

CachingBaseRepository:

```
abstract class CachingBaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    use ScopeActiveTrait;

    protected $model;

    public function all()
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.'.all', $minutes = 10, function () {
            return $this->model->get();
        });
    }

    public function allEnables()
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.'.enables', $minutes = 10, function () {
            return $this->model->active()->get();
        });
    }

    public function list(string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [])
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.'.list', $minutes = 10, function () use($with, $orderByColumn, $orderBy) {
            return $this->model->with($with)
                ->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)
                ->get();
        });
    }

    public function listWithPaginate(string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [], int $perPage = 10)
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.'.listWithPaginate', $minutes = 10, function () use($with, $orderByColumn, $orderBy, $perPage) {
            return $this->model->with($with)
                ->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)
                ->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
        });
    }

    public function create(array $data): int
    {
        return $this->model->create($data)->id;
        // delete cache: all, enables, list, listWithPaginate
    }

    public function update(array $data, int $id, string $attribute = 'id'): void
    {
        $this->model->where($attribute, '=', $id)->update($data);
        // delete cache: all, enables, list, listWithPaginate
    }

    public function delete(int $id): void
    {
        $this->model->destroy($id);
        // delete cache: all, enables, list, listWithPaginate
    }

    public function find(int $id)
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.".{$id}", $minutes = 60, function () use ($id) {
            return $this->model->find($id);
        });
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.".all", $minutes = 60, function (){
            return $this->model;
        });
    }

    public function getFirst(int $id)
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.".{$id}", $minutes = 60, function () use ($id) {
            return $this->model->where('id', $id)->first();
        });
    }

    public function findOrFail(int $id)
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->model.".{$id}", $minutes = 60, function () use ($id) {
            return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        });
    }
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
abstract class BaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    use ScopeActiveTrait;

    protected $model;

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->model->get();
    }

    public function allEnables()
    {
        return $this->model->active()->get();
    }

    public function list(string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [])
    {
        return $this->model->with($with)
            ->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)
            ->get();
    }

    public function listWithPaginate(string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [], int $perPage = 10)
    {
        return $this->model->with($with)
            ->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)
            ->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
    }

    public function create(array $data): int
    {
        return $this->model->create($data)->id;
    }

    public function update(array $data, int $id, string $attribute = 'id'): void
    {
        $this->model->where($attribute, '=', $id)->update($data);
    }

    public function delete(int $id): void
    {
        $this->model->destroy($id);
    }

    public function find(int $id)
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function getFirst(int $id)
    {
        return $this->model->where('id', $id)->first();
    }

    public function findOrFail(int $id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

PageRepository:

```
class PageRepository extends BaseRepository implements PageRepositoryInterface
{

    public function __construct(Page $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    public function search(string $query, string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [], int $perPage = 10)
    {
        return $this->model->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->with($with)->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
    }

    public function getTextPageFromSlug(string $slug)
    {
        return $this->model->active()->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    }

}
```

CachingPageRepository

```
class CachingPageRepository extends CachingBaseRepository implements PageRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(Page $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    public function search(string $query, string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [], int $perPage = 10)
    {
        return Cache::remember('page.all', $minutes = 10, function () use($query, $orderByColumn, $with, $orderBy, $perPage) {
            return $this->model->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->with($with)->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)->paginate($perPage)->appends(request()->query());
        });
    }


    public function getTextPageFromSlug(string $slug)
    {
        return Cache::remember("users.{$slug}", $minutes = 60, function () use ($slug) {
            return $this->model->active()->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        });
    }
}
```

PageRepositoryInterface:

```
interface PageRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface
{

    public function search(string $query, string $orderByColumn, string $orderBy = 'desc', array $with = [], int $perPage = 30);


    public function getTextPageFromSlug(string $slug);

}
```

I want to add cache to my website in the above code. My controller looks like this:

```
protected $model;


    public function __construct(PageRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        $this->model = $repository;
    }


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('query') != "") {
            $pages = $this->model->search($request->input('query'), 'id', 'asc', [],  30);
        } else {
            $pages = $this->model->listWithPaginate('id', 'desc', [],  30);
        }
        return view('admin.pages.list', ['pages' => $pages]);
    }
```

When I run the above code I get the error:

> ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function
>   App\Repositories\PageRepository::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /var/www/app/Providers/PageServiceProvider.php on line 22 and exactly
>   1 expected

Earlier, when I didn't have the cache on the page, my PageServiceProvider looked like this:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            PageRepositoryInterface::class,
            PageRepository::class
        );
    }
```

And the code ran without problems.

How can I repair it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From _construct in PageRepository, your $model is a Page.  The constructor needs the model/page to instantiate a new PageRepository:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(PageRepositoryInterface::class, function ($app) {
        return new CachingPageRepository(
            new PageRepository(new Page())  //constructor for PageRepository needs a model
        );
    });
}

public function provides()
{
    return [
        PageRepositoryInterface::class,
    ];
```

I put "new Page()" in there but I can't really tell where you get your new instance of page from.  However, it's clear from the constructor that you need to input an instance of Page there:

```
public function __construct(Page $model) 
{
    $this->model = $model;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\Caching\CachingPageRepository::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Page, instance of App\Repositories\PageRepository given, called in /var/www/app/Providers/PageServiceProvider.php on line 23```

Comment: Well, that error message is self-explanatory.  You need to make sure you include/require the App\Model\Page class and that you're passing an instance of that class to PageRespository.

Comment: Yes, it's help. Thank you all for your help!!! :). Now have error:

public function listWithPaginate...
    {
        return Cache::remember($this->cacheKey.'.listWithPaginate', $minutes = 10, function () use($with, $orderByColumn, $orderBy, $perPage) {
            return $this->model->with($with)
                ->orderBy($orderByColumn, $orderBy)
                ...
        });
    }
in line: return $this->model->with($with)
Error:

Call to undefined method App\Repositories\PageRepository::with()
Why it's not work ?